# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Object>> get exception if ApiResponse less than 2 JSON Object

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to convert JSON string to object.

My model classes:

```
public class ResponseData<obj> where obj : class
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Boolean isSuccess { get; set; }
    public  obj data{ get; set; }
}

public class Registration
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int eventId { get; set; }
    public string eventTitle { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

JSON String

```
{
  "message": "Success",
  "isSuccess": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "eventId": 1,
      "eventTitle": "Test Event",
      "startDate": "2020-10-10T00:00:00",
      "status": "Pending"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "eventId": 4,
      "eventTitle": "dung test",
      "startDate": "2020-10-15T00:00:00",
      "status": "Denied"
    }
  ]
}
```

My JsonConvert code

```
ResponseData<IList<Registration>> responseListRegistration = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData<IList<Registration>>>(apiResponse);
```

**Problem**: my code run fine as long as JSON String "data" has more than 1 object. When "data" has only one object, it run into exception. And the thing is "data" may has more than 1 object.

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[APT_Admin.Models.Registration]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'data.id', line 1, position 51.

**I've tried**: List, IList, IEnumerable but it all the same.

1 Object JSON

```
{
  "message": "Success",
  "isSuccess": true,
  "data": {
    "id": 6,
    "eventId": 1,
    "eventTitle": "Test Event",
    "startDate": "2020-10-10T00:00:00",
    "status": "Pending"
  }
}
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Can you add sample of json with only one element? Is it still in an array?

Comment: Copy and pasted your code above and it works just fine for me. What version of Newtonsoft are you using?

Comment: @Andy im using Newtonsoft 12.0.3

Comment: @Kalten im added

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize two different json structure in one single class model, you need to use a custom `JsonConverter`. The `JsonReader`  allow you to read the first token. If it's a `[` you will need to deserialize as list. If it's a `{`, an object.

```
void Main()
{
    var json = "{ \"message\": \"Success\", \"isSuccess\": true, \"data\": [ { \"id\": 6, \"eventId\": 1, \"eventTitle\": \"Test Event\", \"startDate\": \"2020-10-10T00:00:00\", \"status\": \"Pending\" }, { \"id\": 1, \"eventId\": 4, \"eventTitle\": \"dung test\", \"startDate\": \"2020-10-15T00:00:00\", \"status\": \"Denied\" } ]}";
    var json2 = "{ \"message\": \"Success\", \"isSuccess\": true, \"data\": { \"id\": 6, \"eventId\": 1, \"eventTitle\": \"Test Event\", \"startDate\": \"2020-10-10T00:00:00\", \"status\": \"Pending\" }}";

    var multiItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData<IList<Registration>>>(json);
    var singleItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData<IList<Registration>>>(json2);
}

public class ResponseData<T> where T : class
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Boolean isSuccess { get; set; }

    [JsonConverterAttribute(typeof(ItemOrListConverter))]
    public T data { get; set; }
}
public class Registration
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int eventId { get; set; }
    public string eventTitle { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class ItemOrListConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var itemType = objectType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);

        var result = Activator.CreateInstance(listType) as IList;

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            var singleObject = serializer.Deserialize(reader, itemType);
            result.Add(singleObject);
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray)
                    break;

                var singleObject = serializer.Deserialize(reader, itemType);
                result.Add(singleObject);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

### System.Text.Json

```
void Main()
{
    var json = "{ \"message\": \"Success\", \"isSuccess\": true, \"data\": [ { \"id\": 6, \"eventId\": 1, \"eventTitle\": \"Test Event\", \"startDate\": \"2020-10-10T00:00:00\", \"status\": \"Pending\" }, { \"id\": 1, \"eventId\": 4, \"eventTitle\": \"dung test\", \"startDate\": \"2020-10-15T00:00:00\", \"status\": \"Denied\" } ]}";
    var json2 = "{ \"message\": \"Success\", \"isSuccess\": true, \"data\": { \"id\": 6, \"eventId\": 1, \"eventTitle\": \"Test Event\", \"startDate\": \"2020-10-10T00:00:00\", \"status\": \"Pending\" }}";

    JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseData<IList<Registration>>>(json).Dump();
    JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ResponseData<IList<Registration>>>(json2).Dump();
}

public class ResponseData<T> where T : class
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Boolean isSuccess { get; set; }

    [JsonConverterAttribute(typeof(ItemOrListConverterFactory))]
    public T data { get; set; }
}
public class Registration
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int eventId { get; set; }
    public string eventTitle { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class ItemOrListConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)
        => typeToConvert
            .GetInterfaces()
            .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));

    public override System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter? CreateConverter(Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var itemType = typeToConvert
            .GetInterfaces()
            .First(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
            .GetGenericArguments()[0];

        if (typeToConvert.IsInterface)
        {
            typeToConvert = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);
        }

        return (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(ItemOrListConverter<>).MakeGenericType(typeToConvert),
            args: new object[] { itemType });
    }
}

public class ItemOrListConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
{
    private readonly Type _itemType;

    public ItemOrListConverter(Type itemType)
    {
        _itemType = itemType;
    }

    public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var result = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance(typeToConvert);

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartObject)
        {
            var singleObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, _itemType, options);
            result.Add(singleObject);
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndArray)
                    break;
                var singleObject = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(ref reader, _itemType, options);
                result.Add(singleObject);
            }
        }

        return (T)result;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```